# EstimateFeatureMapQualityForHosting always returns "Insufficient"

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

The extension method [EstimateFeatureMapQualityForHosting](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity-arf/class/Google/XR/ARCoreExtensions/ARAnchorManagerExtensions#estimatefeaturemapqualityforhosting) always returns `Insufficient` no matter how hard I try to move around the camera.

I checked that the `Pose` I give is indeed the Camera's pose.

I tested it on several devices, including a Pixel 6.

I tried polling every frame and polling on user input every few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is there is a mistake in the documentation/samples.

[EstimateFeatureMapQualityForHosting](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity-arf/class/Google/XR/ARCoreExtensions/ARAnchorManagerExtensions#estimatefeaturemapqualityforhosting) expects the camera pose in the **local** coordinates.

It's not explicitly written in the documentation, *but* in the sample of the unity package they also take the global pose. Luckly their `ARSessionOrigin` is at (0,0,0) so it doesn't matter if you take the local or global pose. I didn't have the `ARSessionOrigin` not at (0,0,0) so for me there *was* a difference.